# Kubernetes Loadbalancer redirecting to HTTPs when application is on port 80

Tags: kubernetes

I've deployed a series of deployments and services to a Kubernetes cluster with a load balancer. When I try to access my app this does not work as my application is exposed on port 80 but the URL is always redirected to port 443 (HTTPS). I suspect this is to do with the fact that the cluster IP is on port 443.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
db           NodePort       10.245.175.203   <none>           5432:30029/TCP   25m
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.245.0.1       <none>           443/TCP          8m
redis        NodePort       10.245.197.157   <none>           6379:31277/TCP   25m
web          LoadBalancer   10.245.126.122   123.12.123.123   80:31430/TCP     25m
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to your application itself redirecting to port `443`.  What type of application is it?

This service exposed on port `443` has nothing to do with your application:

```
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.245.0.1       <none>           443/TCP          8m
```

It's basically an internal service that allows you to access the kube-apiserver within your cluster.

You could try just setting up the `LoadBalancer` to listen on port `443` directly. Only you would have to port `80` traffic wouldn't work. If you want the port `80` redirects to work I suggest you use an [`Ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) controller like [nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). Something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: your-ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - yourhostname.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: yourhostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 443
```

You will also have to create a TLS secret holding your cert and key:

```
$ kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --key /tmp/tls.key --cert /tmp/tls.crt
```